# How to execute below MSSQL query using mulesoft database connector?

Tags: sql-server, mule

```
declare @column1 datetime2    =2020-07-10 13:49:51,611
declare @column2 varchar(50)   ='qazwsxedcrfv'
declare @column3 bigint     =302316811
declare @column4 datetime    =2020-07-10 13:49:51,611
declare @column5 varchar(50)   ='abcdexfgh'

insert into table_name (col1,col2,col3,col4,col5) values 
(@column1,@column2,@column3,@column4,@column5)
```

How to execute this syntax using mulesoft database connector.

Comment: Not a direct answer, but if you have some microservice being orchestrated by Mule, you could just execute the query there.

Comment: Adding that the script is not valid T-SQL syntax. The datetime literals must be enclosed in single quotes and you'll need to use a decimal point separator instead of comma for the fractional seconds.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Mule Database Connector to execute the insert, however you don't use the declares. The connector uses basically JDBC. You'll probably need to convert the datetimes to JDBC dates.

Example:

```
<db:config name="dbConfig">
    <db:mssql-connection
    host="..."
    port="..."
    user="..."
    password="..."
    databaseName="..." />
</db:config>



<db:insert config-ref="dbConfig">
    <db:sql>
        INSERT INTO table_name (col1,col2,col3,col4,col5)
        VALUES (:col1,:col2,:col3,:col4,:col5)
    </db:sql>
    <db:input-parameters>#[
        output application/java
        ---
        {
            col1: |2020-07-10T13:49:51,611| as DateTime { class : "java.sql.Date"},
            col2: 'qazwsxedcrfv',
            col3: 302316811,
            col4: |2020-07-10T13:49:51,611| as DateTime { class : "java.sql.Date"},
            col5: 'abcdexfgh'
        }]
    </db:input-parameters>
</db:insert>
```

Comment: Hi @aled thanks for your time.
I have tried this solution but it gives syntax error. Application not able to deploy successfully.
I am using mule 3.8 community edition.
could you please help me on how to execute this syntax in community edition.

Comment: I see. The solution I gave is for Mule 4. I'll try to update it for Mule 3.